# How do you get a data frame that dont match in two data frames?

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

df1

```
ServerName
web01
web02
j2k101
tomcat101  
prdc1001
```

and df2

```
ServerName Application
Web01      Web
j2k10      Internal
tomcat101  Application
```

I want to use merge command to merge df1 and df2 to get all the ServerNames that have Application associated with them as this

```
merge(df1,df2, by=c("ServerName")
```

I also want to get a list of servers that don't have Application name. How would I do that?

Comment: you can use `all = TRUE` like this `merge(df1, df2 ,  by=c("ServerName", all = TRUE)` also read `?merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1[!(df1$ServerName %in% df2$ServerName),]
```

Note, you have inconsistent capitalisation. If you want this fixed:

```
df1[!(toupper(df1$ServerName) %in% toupper(df2$ServerName)),]
```

Comment: Careful with your bracketing. It doesn't result in an error, but its not great form. from precendence:  You can use this for %in% :
! 1:10 %in% c(2, 3, 5, 7) # same as !(1:10 %in% c(2, 3, 5, 7))
## but we strongly advise to use the "!( ... )" form in this case!
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html